# Request Tracker 4.2.8 PHP REST API download attachment

Tags: php, rt

I am trying to download attachments from RT 4.2.8 tickets using PHP REST API (https://github.com/dersam/RTPHPLib).
I've used Ticket Attachment Content and Ticket Attachment. They return some kind of string or array like this (basically it outputs the file content):

````
   Array
(
    [%PDF-1.4
%����
] => 
    [10 0 obj
<>
endobj

] => 
    [15 0 obj
<>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<4DCDA9C01A05A34BB7A89B62345FD905><4DCDA9C01A05A34BB7A89B62345FD905>]/Index[10 7]/Info 9 0 R/Length 36/Prev 805889/Root 11 0 R/Size 17/Type/XRef/W[1 2 0]>>stream
] => 
    [h�bbd`b`�db`�eb`����^��"��
] => 
    [endstream
endobj
startxref
] => 
    [0
] => 
    [%%EOF
] => 
    [16 0 obj
<>stream
] => 
    [h�b```f``����33 �������L f(f`�ca```h�o�1���iF �`�] => 
    [O
] => 
    [endstream
endobj
11 0 obj
<>
endobj
12 0 obj
<>>>/Rotate 270/Type/Page>>
endobj
````

I've tried to write this with php fwrite/file_put_contents to a tmp file and then download it, but it won't open.

How can I download the ticket attachments locally? I want this to be dynamic (no matter the file extension)

Answer (score 0):

For binary content, it is necessary to make an additional call to `getAttachmentContent`. This will return the file contents in their original encoding.

The issue comes from RT using UTF-8 in its response, which also encodes the `Content` section. Unfortunately, RT does not store the original encoding of the attachment, resulting in an unreliable `Content` section, making it impossible for RTPHPLib to guess intelligently.

See https://github.com/dersam/RTPHPLib/issues/66 for some recent discussion on this.